# Sum of rows in one column based on values in adjacent column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I need to sum a range (D20:D22) but exclude any values in an adjacent column (G20:G22) where the Column G values is <-2. The resulting value is the divisor in a second calculation.

For example:

- D20:D22

  - values = 6, 10 and 12 (sum = 28)
- G20:G22

  - values = 1.87. 3.52 and 4.84
- G20 is less than 2, so D20 is excluded from the sum
- Expected sum: D20:D22 = 22 (10 + 12)

---

- Cell I20  = 8.36
- I20 divided by adjusted sum of D20:D22

  - = 0.38 (8.36/22)

---

I think that `sumifs` is probably part of the solution, but I can't work out how to write the formula.

See my [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-b-KYxxMSsxuLOXmgObC-6sehmewoxir6DuoRG2YpP8/edit?usp=sharing). The formula is on sheet "BOD".

Hope this isn't too confusing.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`=I20/sumifs(D20:D22,G20:G22,">2")`

[Sumifs documehtation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)

Comment: Thank you @ Tedinoz

Comment: No worries, Jake. If this answer was useful then you might consider accepting it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)